# How to fix strange behavior of anonymously created structure, when called in function?

Tags: c, class, private, encapsulation

I'm trying to recreate an encapsulation principle in ANSI-C for educational purposes. What I essentially did was making some structure in *.c* file:

```
struct _private
{
    unsigned char SizeInBytes;
    unsigned char* matrix;
    struct Stack* S;
    unsigned char ByteX;
};
```

which represented variables I wanted to be unseen. Then in *.h* file inside the struct (class) I created an opaque pointer:

```
struct Maze
{
    void* _private;
};
```

which I assign later in constructor function like this:

```
void* Maze_ctor(void* self, va_list *ap)
{
    struct Maze* this = self;

    this->DimX = va_arg(*ap, unsigned char);
    this->DimY = va_arg(*ap, unsigned char);

    this->_private = &(struct _private)          // passing address of struct to void*
    { 
        .SizeInBytes = this->DimX*this->DimY >> 1,
        .S = new(Stack),
        .ByteX = this->DimX % 8 > 0 ? this->DimX / 8 + 1 : this->DimX / 8
    };
    // 
    private.matrix = (unsigned char*)malloc(private.ByteX*this->DimY);
    S = new(Stack);     // this in my new() and it works similar to C++ new

    for (int i = 0; i < private.ByteX*this->DimY; i++)
        *(private.matrix + i) = 0;
}
```

At this point everything works fine, but then I'm trying to call the Next() method:

```
int Next(void* self, ...)
{
    struct Maze* this = self;

    struct _private *r = this->_private;

    short t;

    toBinary(this);          // after this point the struct private breaks
}
```

the prototype of toBinary() is:

```
void toBinary(const void* self)
{
    // somehow char local is defined and equals to 204??
    struct Maze *this = self;
    struct _private *r = this->_private;

    unsigned char local;     // right after this point SizeInBytes equals to 204!
...
}
```

the question is: how to fix this problem. **Using C++ is prohibited!**
for the interested ones: here is new()

```
void* new(const void* _class,...)
{
    const struct Class* class = _class; // we need to convert pointer from void* to class* safely
    void *p = calloc(1, class->size);   // allocation of memory for class .using size param

    assert(p);                          // if Null -> throw an error
    *(const struct Class**)p = class;   // safe assignment of class pointer to (value) of p, to have memory and built in funcs
    if (class->ctor)                    // if has constructor with some dynal in it, execute with varargs on its input
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, _class);           // 
        p = class->ctor(p, &ap);        // pass arguments as a list of pointers.
        va_end(ap);
    }
    return p;                           //returns a pointer to class pointer (weird but worx)
}
```

Comment: If I’m not entirely mistaken you’re creating a local struct and assigning it to the pointer. After the function finishes it’s gone and you have a dangling pointer. You need dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the compiler is set to /TC, this ought to be C

Comment: Do you want C or TC (whatever TC may be)?

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov If you want to implement the concepts of OOP in C there are lots of courses whose contents you can find online.  Here please paste a code that we can execute to see ourselves what you mean.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie /TC is a MSVC compiler option for compiling C code

Comment: @alk, ah..yes, it is. Didn't see that.

Comment: @alinsoar https://github.com/Agrael1/Veritas-2D/tree/Unstable/ConsoleApplication5 It is a complicated project

Comment: If this is C, then what does `new` do?

Comment: @alk it **IS** pointed out in the comment

Comment: Ah well, stopped parsing with its 1st occurrence.

Comment: Change this `this->_private = &(struct _private)` to be `this->_private = new(struct _private); {*this->_private = (struct _private){ 
        .SizeInBytes = this->DimX*this->DimY >> 1,
        .S = new(Stack),
        .ByteX = this->DimX % 8 > 0 ? this->DimX / 8 + 1 : this->DimX / 8
    };}` then.

Comment: @alk this needs to be class then, my new() cannot make instances of a struct, but it gave me an idea

Comment: "*Class*" err what? In C?

Comment: @alk struct Class{}; yes, this is a hack, but it worx :)

Comment: Last guess: Then use `new(_private)` instead of `new(struct _private)`. Dare to show the implementation of `new()`?

Comment: Ok, so then what is `Stack` in `new(Stack)`? Sort of a constant global class descriptor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190584/discussion-between-ilya-pakhmutov-and-alk).

Comment: [Object-oriented Programming with ANSI C (Chapter 2)](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) is well worth the read.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I read it, but several things are not entirely understood by me. That's why I'm practicing

Comment: The key there is the first member of the class/struct holds the size of the struct which allows calling new and obtaining the required size from the object itself. (I had to scratch my head a couple of times with that too)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin there is almost nothing stated to encapsulation principles I'm referring to. I do not understand the second half of the book, instead I did virtual functions table and static declaration for my classes

Comment: That's fair. The nuts and bolts of the method used there, along with the encapsulation, come out of chapters 1-3 -- I agree, the 2nd half of that paper is a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the problem is that you created a local object and assign it to a pointer `this`. Outside that function, the value of `this` is not valid.

You code,

```
void* Maze_ctor(void* self, va_list *ap)
{
//....
// this creates a temporary object and will be destroyed after Maz_ctor returns.

this->_private = &(struct _private)          // passing address of struct to void*
{ 
    .SizeInBytes = this->DimX*this->DimY >> 1,
    .S = new(Stack),
    .ByteX = this->DimX % 8 > 0 ? this->DimX / 8 + 1 : this->DimX / 8
};
// ---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sami Kuhmonen for pointing out on dynamic allocation and @CS Pei for mistake analysis. The thing I did to fix this is:

```
struct Maze
{
    char _private[32]; // allocate the memory size of struct(32)
}


// assign values to void ptr
private.SizeInBytes = this->DimX*this->DimY >> 1;
private.S = new(Stack);
private.ByteX = this->DimX % 8 > 0 ? this->DimX / 8 + 1 : this->DimX / 8;
private.matrix = (unsigned char*)malloc(private.ByteX*this->DimY);
```

this now works as intended, but a little slower